# Is it possible to connect a broadband USB dongle to a D-Link DIR-600M Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a [D-Link DIR-600M](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-600-wireless-n-150-home-router) Router which does not have a USB port. It has Ethernet port. I want to share my Internet connection (wireless through Dongle) over Wi-Fi. How can I connect without modem.

In the user installation guide connection is shown with the help of a modem. But I want to connect it with my dongle (USB Port).

Also the address `http://192.168.0.1/` (as mentioned in guide) is not opening.

Comment: can i use a cable that has Ethernet at one end and USB at the other? will it work?

Comment: One way of sharing your internet is to make another network in your PC. Connect this network with the existing network(which has internet access) and then you can share your new network.

Comment: @CZAbhinav Can you please explain the process. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an Ad Hoc network connection by following the directions below:

Windows 7

1) Open the Start Menu.

2) Click Control Panel.

3) Click Network and Internet.

4) Click Network and Sharing Center.

5) Under Change your networking settings, click Set up a new connection or network.

6) Select Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer) network.

7) Click on Next twice.

8) Enter the Network name such as "MyNetwork".

9) Select the Security WAP (or WEP).

10) Enter the Security key or password.

11) Check Save this network check box.

12) Click Turn on Internet connection sharing.

Comment: But I think I would not be able to use my internet connection on phone. Will I??

Comment: you can use it on your phone. Your laptop will act as a wifi hotspot so all the wifi enabled devices can be connected.

Comment: I don't have a laptop. I want to use it on a desktop. I think it will not work on a desktop?

Comment: Then I guess this method will not work. If you can purchase a wifi dongle and connect it to your desktop, then it might work.!

Comment: Do you know how to install virtual wifi router on desktop..If this can be done then I'm sure it will solve my problem. :)

Comment: don't have an idea.! Google it you will find many ways of doing it my friend.!

Comment: I remember, a few years ago I tried it but failed. But as if you are saying let me google it once again. By the way, thank you for cooperating :)

Comment: I have found this [link](http://www.virtualwifirouter.com/p/configuring-first-time.html) & this [one](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) , hope it helps you. If you are satisfied with answer, please consider selecting it as answer to avoid unanswered questions on stackexchange.!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the links. I will try them as soon as possible. Please give me a few days time(busy now for a few days)If it works then I will rate this answer as appropriate. Thanks

Comment: The following error comes, "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation." How to fix this?....Also in Device Manager >> Network Adapters, "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter" is not coming even if 'Show hidden devices' is enabled from "View" section.

Comment: I have tried 'netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow' and 'netsh wlan start hostednetwork' in cmd(admin) but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: This command is incomplete `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow`. You have to enter the full command `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=(wifi name) key=(wifi password)`, replace `wifi name` with the name you want for your wifi and `wifi password` will be your password. After this enter `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` . But i don't know it will work for you because you don't have wifi in your desktop.!

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it also. Nothing works. How can I install the Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport adapter on my desktop. Do you know?

Comment: Brother this (or any other hotspot software) will not work in your case because you don't have a wifi in your system.

Comment: Is this a hardware problem?

Comment: Its not a hardware problem. Purchase a Wifi module for your system, install its drivers. Then install mhotspot software in your system and then you can share your desktop's internet with other devices like phone/tablet/laptop

Comment: Where can I buy a wifi module?

Comment: Now this is very general question. Obviously you can purchase it from any computer shop

Comment: And they will assemble it in the hardware? ..by the way thanks :)

Comment: Aashish wifi dongle kbhi suna nhi hai kya.? see [here](http://images.wisegeek.com/usb-wifi-dongle.jpg) you just plug it install drivers and then you can access wifi networks

Comment: Yeah I have heard about wifi dongle. I was just thinking about something else(when you said module) :P Ummm...So I need to spend money and nothing could be done to install the virtual router. Am i right?

Comment: yes this time you are right. Purchase a wifi dongle then everything can be set. Purchase a good one and then if you find any error tell me.!

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately this isn't possible.**

> A router has a specific, physical port(s) that it uses to communicate
>   with the outside world. Any connection outside of your network (i.e.
>   the Internet) has to go via this port. There's nothing you can do to
>   change this.
>
> However, you may want to consider buying an appropriate router. The
>   dongle acts as your outside connection, it attaches to the router via
>   a USB port and you then connect your devices to the router as normal.
>   If you do go down this road, just make sure you buy an appropriate
>   router. Lots of them will have a USB port, but solely for file or
>   printer sharing.

[Here Is the Link](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2221584/connect-mobile-hotspot-router-ethernet-connections.html#13731204)

Comment: I have a modem. Can in any way I can connect my dongle with modem and then modem with router?

Comment: No Sir it's not possible.As the modem that you have mentioned above doesn't have a usb port build in so it won't work.Although buying an another modem with Build in function(USB port) can solve your problem for sure.